# Une inversion s’impose-t-elle dans « De X ne dépend pas seulement Y, mais aussi Z » ?

Tags: expressions, inversion

> 1 : **De** cette élection **ne dépend pas seulement** l’avenir de notre peuple, **mais aussi** la sauvegarde de toute vie sur l’île.
>
> 2 : **De** cette élection **dépend non seulement** l’avenir de notre peuple, **mais aussi** la sauvegarde de toute vie sur l’île.

Le seul bémol, c'est que sans une inversion, je me demande si les deux sujets (Y et Z) ne se trouvent pas trop éloignés l'un de l'autre pour en faciliter notre compréhension.

> 3 : **Non seulement** l’avenir de notre peuple **dépend de** cette élection, **mais aussi** la sauvegarde de toute vie sur l’île.

Comment: L'inversion ne s'impose pas mais elle possible.

Comment: On peut aussi dire: "Cette élection conditionne non seulement l’avenir de notre peuple, mais aussi la sauvegarde de toute vie sur l’île".

Answer (score 2):

Bien que ces énoncés aient le même sens, ils ne sont pas équivalents. Le choix de l'un ou l'autre est lié à la cohérence de cet énoncé avec le contexte.
Par exemple:

De cette élection dépend non seulement...mais aussi... (complément verbe sujet) sera utilisé lorsque le contexte avant parle de l'élection. On pourrait avoir par exemple:

Non à l'abstention! Il est très important d'aller voter. DE CETTE ELECTION dépend non seulement...mais aussi...

Quant à l'inversion verbe sujet elle est obligatoire ici parce que:

*Lorsque une partie de la phrase est mise en vedette au début, à la place habituellement occupée par le sujet, cela entraine parfois, mais pas toujours, une inversion verbe sujet.

*Quand le sujet est déjà dans l'air, déjà saisi, de 'statut repris', anticipé, que son choix est bloqué par le contexte: ici les électeurs connaissent déjà les problèmes qu'il faudrait résoudre, l'inversion verbe sujet est obligatoire. La présence de 'de' qui est liée à la sémantique du verbe 'dépendre' est d'ailleurs un indice de ce statut repris.

Answer (score 1):

La formulation sans inversion est tout à fait correcte mais je placerais le verbe en fin de phrase :

> Non seulement l’avenir de notre peuple mais aussi la sauvegarde de toute vie sur l’île dépend de cette élection.